# Rsync create symbolic links only

Tags: shell, unix, rsync

I currently have rsync working well. It copies all my files from one directory to another directory. The only thing is it is physically copying the files.

I have a lot of large files that I don't want to have a duplicate of all the files. I just want to create a symbolic link in the new directory so that I can serve the data on a webpage.  The source directory has some scripts and files I don't want the public to see. I'm moving the safe data to the web root (destination).

What I would like rsync to do is any new files in the source directory would create links into the destination. That way I am not using up my hard drive space like I currently am doing. What I have works perfect except for doing the symbolic link aspect to it. Is there a way to have rsync track and create symbolic links?

```
rsync -aP --exclude="file.sql" --exclude="*~" --exclude=".*" --exclude="*.sh" . ${destination}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the appropriate permissions for files you don't want to show?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cp -aR -s` (Linux or FreeBSD) or `cp --archive --recursive --symbolic-link` (Linux) to create symbolic links to the source files in the destination directory instead of copies.  Note that `-s` is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a symlink, but you might be able to work with `--link-dest=DIR`.  It creates a hard link which will create a new name for the same file.  This will behave similarly to a softlink as long as:

- Both files are on the same filesystem
- You don't plan to delete the original and not the copy (the symlink would break but a hard-link won't)
- You don't have anything explicitly checking to see if it's a softlink

Answer (score 0):

Can lndir be useful to you. According to manual it creates a shadow directory of symbolic links to another directory tree.

Comment: The problem with this is when you remove files (which I will be doing all the time) they are lost in space...

Answer (score 0):

I think `master_delivery` is probably the best tool for this. With the already introduced `--link-dest` option of `rsync`, files which are not the same will be copied. If you don't mind the situation where copies and hardlinks are mixed, you can use `rsync`, but if you want to eliminate duplicates completely, use `master_delivery`.

Usage is:

```sh
gem install master_delivery
master_delivery -m <path_to_master> -d <path_to_delivery_root>
```