# Can rsync be used to make only hard links, not copies?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a numbers of files and dirs under /data. I want to use rsync to create hardlinks in a backups directory. The /data/dir_1 ... dir_n/backups already exits.

```
Starting point...
/data/dir_1 ... dir_n/file_1 ... file_n

Ending point...
/data/dir_1 ... dir_n/backups/dir_1 ... dir_n/file_1 ... file_n (hardlinks back to /data/dir_1 ... dir_n/file_1 ... file_n)
```

Is this possible with just rsync?

Is this possible with just rsync and recursion to replicate for an entire directory hierarchy?

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is questions about *software development*. For questions about command-line usage of UNIX tools, consider [unix.se].

Comment: The software I'm developing has this requirement. I wonder why there are Cassandra Operations questions on StackOverflow? This is an example of a reason why a friend of mine has told me to quit using StackOverflow. Software developers ought to know this stuff too. Thanks for the down vote. It's much appreciated. Cheers sir.

Comment: There this example.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders?rq=1

Comment: And this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887766/rsync-create-symbolic-links-only?rq=1

Comment: (1) Don't assume that the people commenting and the people downvoting are one and the same -- the downvote you thanked me for was not mine. (2) Site rules change over time. Just because something slipped through in the past doesn't make it acceptable; the only canonical sources for current site rules are the Help Center and consensus on meta. (3) It doesn't matter if a question is about something a developer "ought to know". The wording is *unique to software development* -- ie. it should be something but nobody *except* software developers needs to know.

Comment: ...to be clear re: source for said wording -- see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, fourth bullet point, and note that it's an "and", not an "or", connecting that to the other criteria.

Comment: Indeed... you are correct. That was indeed a bad assumption on my part. I will keep that in mind in the future Charles. My apologies for allowing my work stress to seep into StackOverflow and on to you. Per your suggestion, I've joined Unix & Linux StageExchange. Thank you for taking the time to explain. It is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rsync -av --link-dest=src_dir src_dir/ new_dir/
```

Comment: Deleted my "non-answer" because this is the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Could try an rsync wrapper, if you want more than one such link tree for backup purposes: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/Backup.remote.html#rsync